# Multiple IFs in one excel formula

Tags: excel

I have created this formula but it's giving me a #VALUE! error. Can someone help to see what is wrong? Thank you.

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(AND(C2="Female",OR(E2="Black")),((141*(POWER(MIN(A2/0.7,1),-0.329))*POWER(MAX(A2/0.7,1),-1.209)*POWER(0.993,F2)*1.018*1.159)),((141*(POWER(MIN(A2/0.7,1),-0.411))*POWER(MAX(A2/0.7,1),-1.209)*POWER(0.993,F2)*1.018)))),IF(AND(C2="Male",OR(E2="Black")),((141*(POWER(MIN(A2/0.9,1),-0.329))*POWER(MAX(A2/0.9,1),-1.209)*POWER(0.993,F2)*1.159)),((141*(POWER(MIN(A2/0.9,1),-0.411))*POWER(MAX(A2/0.9,1),-1.209)*POWER(0.993,F2))))
```

Comment: What does it show when you click "Evaluate Formula" in the Formulas tab? That should help provide insight.

Comment: It just shows the same formula

Comment: If you view it under function arguments, there is number results but when you exit out there is the #VALUE! again on the cell.

Comment: That's what excel gave me when it auto corrected my formula. I don't know if that is correct, though.

Comment: So how should I write it correctly? Can you please show it? thanks

Comment: @JVA right, but when you then click "evaluate", it should show you how the calculation is working step by step.

Comment: Hi Bruce, looks like step by step calculation is working correctly. Although I see #N/A in some areas. Thanks.

Comment: If you see #N/A in some areas, how can you come to the conclusion that it is working correctly? Which part of the formula returns #N/A? Also, you don't seem to understand how OR() works, why else would you only have one argument inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You have two IF statements in one cell, separated by a comma. Check the brackets.

The first IF has a nested IF with Female and black, which has a calculation in the TRUE part and another calculation in the FALSE part. The nested IFs are closed correctly.

Then follows a comma and and IF with Male and Black, with a calculation in the TRUE and another calculation in the FALSE part.

You need to check your syntax. You can't have two IFs in one cell like that. Excel does not work like that.

Comment: Thank you teylyn.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so please let me put it here.

To help you with your code, please check the following tips:

1. Put ALL your formulae as text in notepad or textbox. **do not use "=" yet. You may try to use the equal sign to see if your formula is working well. but you have to remove them afterwards**. You can enclose them in parenthesis if it suits you.

E.g.

> 141*(POWER(MIN(A2/0.7,1),-0.329))

into

> (141*(POWER(MIN(A2/0.7,1),-0.329)))

that means it is a single item in your nested function.

2. if you do nested `if` functions, finish the parenthesis first, then the commas before filling the slots with formulas you have.

E.g.

> = if ( , , )

or

> = if ( , ,if( , , if( , , )))

**Note: A single parenthesis will ruin your formula so I do this to eliminate this possibility**

3. Fill your main `if` function with the formula. Copy and paste as is.

Comment: Thank you Jem, I will try your suggestion. Will keep you updated.